# Communication between states i and j implies equality of periodicity of i and j

Tags: number-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

> Claim:$i\leftrightarrow j$ implies $d\left ( i \right )=d\left ( j \right )$

Suppose $i\leftrightarrow j$:

This implies that j is accessible from i and i is accessible from j.
Then, $\exists n_{1}$ such that $p_{ij}^{n_{1}}>0$ and $\exists n_{2}$ such that $p_{ji}^{n_{2}}>0$

By the chapman kolmogorov equation:

$p_{ii}^{n_{1}+n_{2}} \geq p_{ij}^{n_{1}}p_{ji}^{n_{2}}>0$

since $p_{ii}^{n_{1}+n_{2}}>0$, by definition of periodicity of any state i:

there exists a gcd, say $d_{i}$, that divides $n_{1}+n_{2}$.

Suppose $p_{jj}^{n}>0$.

Then, by the chapman kolmogorov equation:

$p_{ii}^{n_{1}+n_{2}+n} \geq p_{ij}^{n_{1}}p_{jj}^{n}p_{ji}^{n_{2}}
>0$

Again, by periodicity, $d_{i}$ is the greatest common divisor of $n_{1}+n+n_{2}$.

How can I convince myself that $d_{i}$ also divides n?

Counterexample, 2 is the gcd for $8=2+1+5$ but 2 does not divide 1

Comment: Hint: If $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$ then $a\mid (bp + cq)$ for all integers $p,q$.